# degree computation in the proof of Theorem V.1.10 in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Here is our setting: $X$ is a surface (in the sense of chapter V in Hartshorne), $D$ is a reduced curve on $X$ (possibly singular), $C_i$ is an irreducible component of $D$, $f: \tilde{C}_i \rightarrow C_i$ is the normalization map. Hartshorne writes

> $\deg f^* (\mathscr{L}(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C_i})$ is just $D. C_i$, because we can represent $\mathscr{L}(D)$ as a difference of nonsingular curves meeting $C_i$ transversally, so this degree is preserved by $f^*$.

I can see that $D \sim E-E'$, where $E$ and $E'$ are nonsingular curves on $X$ meeting $C_i$ transversally. However, how does this give that $\deg f^* (\mathscr{L}(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C_i}) = D. C_i$? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since pullback commutes with tensor products and duals, and intersection product is linear and respects rational equivalence, it suffices to prove that $\deg f^*(\mathcal{L}(E)\otimes\mathcal{O}_{C_i})=E.C_i$ for $E$ a nonsingular curve meeting $C_i$ transversely.

On the one hand, $E.C_i$ is just $\#(E\cap C_i)$ since they meet transversely (cf [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394144/nonsingularity-assumption-in-lemma-v-1-3-in-hartshorne)).

On the other hand, since $E\cap C_i$ is a divisor supported on the regular locus of $C_i$, the pullback of this via $f$, which is an isomorphism on the regular locus, doesn't change. So computing the degree is still the same thing as computing the number of points in the divisor, which didn't change!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here are two things that confuse me: 1) $E \cap C_i$ is a divisor on $C_i$, but $C_i$ might not be nonsingular. On the other hand, Hartshorne has defined the pullback of divisors only for nonsingular curves. 2) $E.C_i = \deg \mathscr{L}(C_i) \otimes \mathcal{O}_E$ because $E$ is nonsingular. On the other hand, in our expression we have  $\mathscr{L}(E) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C_i}$. Would you please add  some more detail to your answer?

Comment: 1) You can perfectly well define $E\cap C_i$ as a Cartier divisor on $C_i$ (supported on the regular locus) and pull back the Cartier divisor, which is defined on any scheme where Cartier divisors make sense. 2) I don't understand what your second point has to do with anything. $E.C_i$ is just the count of the number of points, and so is $\deg f^*(\cdots)$.

Comment: I think I see what you mean; I thought Lemma V.1.3 was playing a role. So if I understand correctly, the fact that $E$ is nonsingular does not play a role, only the fact that $E$ meets $C_i$ transversaly. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.